# node socket.io emit event on page load without loading page in browser

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hello is this possile to:
emit an event when i call a URL in browser or using Postman using node and socket.io
i want to do it without loading socket.io client.

inside my app.js or www file using express framework.

Thank you!

Comment: let me with out loading socket.io in client, how could you even listen to the emitted event in first place.

Comment: Socket.io server is listning. Can't we create a client in node somehow and have it comm with server?

Comment: yes you can create a client and communicate, but for communicating you need to create an instance of socket.io in the client also.